# nested literal objects and filtering by lower case

Tags: javascript, jquery, object-literal

I have a page where I receive query string values like the following:

```
?Target=Customers&Sector=Private
```

it might also take the same values as small letters, depending on the user.

I have the following object on my page:

```
var settings = {
    Target = { T1: "Customer", T2: "Partner", T3 : "Other"  }, 
    Sector = { S1 : "Private", S2 : "Public", S3 : "Other" } 
}
```

I need to take the query string, and get the property names such as T1 , T2 , S1 etc.. as I want to send them somewhere else.

My code to do so looks like this:

```
//Here I am converting all the main settings properties to small letters, in csae the user passes "customer"
 var settingskey, keys = Object.keys(settings);
    var n = keys.length; 
    var newSettings = {};
    while(n--){
        settingskey = keys[n];
        newSettings[settingskey.toLowerCase()] = settings[settingskey];
    }

//Now I have my new object
    var resultArray = "";  // This is the final array where I will fill the values like T1 S1
    //get query string
    var url = window.location.search;
    //get rid of ? character
    url = url.substring(1);
    //separate each key, value pairs
    var keyvalueArray = url.split('&');
    //loop through all key value pairs
    keyvalueArray.forEach(function(keyvalue){
        //get key, ex: Target
        var key = keyvalue.split('=')[0];
        //get value, ex: Customer
        var val = keyvalue.split('=')[1];
        console.log(key);
        console.log(val);

        for(p in newSettings){
            if(p == key.toLowerCase())
            {
                var element = {};
                element =  newSettings[key.toLowerCase()];   
                var elementValue, elementValues = Object.values(element);
                var newElement = {};
                var n = elementValues.length;
                newElement.keys = element.keys; 
                while(n--){

                    elementValue = elementValues[n];
                    newElement[n] = elementValue.toLowerCase();
                }     
                for(var prop in newElement){
                    if(element[prop] == val){
                        classArray+= "." + prop + ", ";
                    }
                }


          break;
        }
    }
});

resultArray = resultArray.substring(0, resultArray.lastIndexOf(',')).trim();
```

Basically, am getting the property names the first time, like Target and sector, and converting them to small letters, and creating a new object. Then am "trying" to create a new object for each one with new "value" so instead of Customer I want customer.

Is there an easy and efficient way to compare query string with nested literal object values/keys in small letters? what if I have other 3-4 nested levels, that means more nested loops.

I want when I pass ?target=customer&sector=private

to return: "T1 S1" as a string

If I pass: ?Target=cuSTomer&sector=oThEr

to return: "T1 S3" as a string

Any idea?

Comment: Please provide clearly the expected output, based on the example.

Comment: There's no point in enumerating the object to search for a key, when you simply can look up the property? Drop the `for(p in newSettings) if(p == key.toLowerCase())` and replace it by `if (key.toLowerCase() in newSettings)` at most.

Comment: @trincot I made an edit at the end of the post, please check it

Comment: @Bergi, and what about the nested object, I need to match the items based on the values

Comment: @Jacky You're out of luck there (unless you invert all objects before), though still that `while` loop and the `newElement` should not be necessary. Just `for (var p in element) if (element[p].toLowerCase() == val) results.push(p.toLowerCase())`

Comment: Isn't there a way to get an object, loop through all properties/values, convert them to lowercase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could swap the key/values at the deepest level of your settings, so that you can directly find 'T1' when given 'target' and 'customer'. So the swapped settings object would then look like:

```
var settings = {
    target: { customer: "T1", partner: "T2", other: "T3"  }, 
    sector: { private: "S1", public: "S2", other: "S3" } 
}
```

Here is a function that makes this swap, and then returns an array of translations made, which you can turn into the space-separated string:

```js
function getCodes(url, settings) {
    var swapped = Object.keys(settings).reduce( function (obj, key) {
        obj[key.toLowerCase()] = Object.keys(settings[key]).reduce ( function (obj2, key2) {
            obj2[settings[key][key2].toLowerCase()] = key2;
            return obj2;
         }, {} ); 
         return obj;
    }, {} );
    return url.toLowerCase().split(/[?&#]/).slice(1).map( function (arg) {
        var parts = arg.split('=');
        return swapped[parts[0].toLowerCase()][parts[1].toLowerCase()];
    } );
}

var url= 'http://www.example.com?Target=Customer&Sector=Private';

var settings = {
    Target: { T1: "Customer", T2: "Partner", T3 : "Other"  }, 
    Sector: { S1 : "Private", S2 : "Public", S3 : "Other" } 
}

var result = getCodes(url, settings).join(' ');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is amazing..! But, is it supported in older browsers? This is ECMAscript 2015 right?

Comment: I tried it on IE11, and I got an error on this line: let swapped = Object.keys(settings).reduce( (obj, key) => { ... it said : Expected ;

Comment: Indeed, this is ES6 (EcmaScript2015). I assumed you had support for this, as you were even using `Object.values` in your own code, which IE does not support either. Anyway, I updated my answer so it should be compatible with ES5 now.

Comment: thank you. How did you know that Object.values isn't supported in IE? How do I become aware of such cases when I do my development?

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance

Comment: I am having this error on IE while executing the line var [key, val] = arg.split('=');  .. I am having: Expected identifier error. Any solution for this? I am on IE 10

Comment: [IE10 is outdated](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support), even IE11 does not support much of EcmaScript2015. Anyway, I updated the code to run in IE10, I hope.